# Finding dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image: Question]
I know that any polynomial in subspace $W$ must have $(x-1)$ as factor so that $p(1)=0$
But I don't understand how $p'(2)=0$ can be incorporated.
Thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: You are correct about the factor of $(x-1)$, but it's not so useful in linear algebra to look at it this way. What is the dimension of $V$? What's the most useful basis to use for $V$? What can you say about the coefficients of a polynomial in terms of those basis elements if $p(1)=0$? What about $p'(2)=0$?

Comment: Can you give another hint ?

Comment: Well, I was trying to get you to work out something similar to the answers below. The point is that a nice basis is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$ so that the dimension is $6$ and the two conditions just give linear equations on the coefficients. If you want to test your understanding of this problem one step further, try to come up with a basis for the four-dimensional subspace $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general element $p(x)\in V$ has the form 
$$p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$$
for some $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{R}$.

The condition $p(1)=0$ means
$$a+b+c+d+e+f=0.$$
The condition $p'(2)=0$ means
$$80a+32b+12c+4d+e=0.$$
So you get that the subspace $W$ consists of the polynomials for which the coefficients are the solutions to the following set of two linear equations in six variables:
$$\begin{cases} 
a+b+c+d+e+f=0\\
80a+32b+12c+4d+e=0
\end{cases}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is using coordinates so the conditions $p(1)=0$ and $p'(2)=0$ transform into two linearly independent equations (as Brian Fitzpatrick shows). Then apply the next formula dim$(W)$=dim$(V)$-$k$, where $k$ is precisely the number of linearly independent equations used to define $W$. So dim$(W)=6-2=4$.

The idea is that each linear independent equation used to define a subspace, subtracts one dimension from it.

Comment: dim$W$ is 4; your answer is correct, but the number of linearity independent equations is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a linear transformation

$$ T:\mathbb{R}_5[x]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$

such that $p \longmapsto (p(1),p'(2))$. It is to see that $T$ is surjective. In particular $kerT=W$; then by the dimension theorem we have:

$$dim(V)=dim( ker T) + dim( Im T)$$

so $6=dim(kerT)+2 \quad \Longrightarrow dim(ker T)=4$.